# What are these clear parts in beef steak?

Tags: beef, food-identification

I can identify the large white strips as **inter-muscular fat**, the red meat as **muscle**, and the small white parts throughout the muscle as **intra-muscular fat**, but what is the clear tissue (circled in orange and blue)?

Should it be removed before serving?

[image: Clear part of beef porterhouse steak]

Answer (score 4):

This looks like gristle.

I wouldn't go hacking at the steak just to remove it. If the eaters don't like it, they are free to cut their steak around it and leave it in their plate.

Comment: @Gimmeethe411, if it's close to the surface like that you can carefully cut it out before cooking, if you cut it out after it will be bad for the appearance of the finished product.